# Mysqli INSERT not working unless all columns are present

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, centos

I was working on a website, I just moved its database from a server running CentOS 6 to a server running CentOS 7, and now my queries don't work unless all columns are present in the query.

[image]

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users(name, user, huser, hpass, mail, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

/* Prepare statement */
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}


/* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $user, $huser, $hpass, $email, $salt);

/* Execute statement */
$stmt->execute();
mysqli_close($conn);
echo "Register succeeded! Please wait...";
```

This script was running fine, the only change done is the mysql server address and credentials. If I add some dummy variables and complete all columns in the query it works fine.

Is this a setting I need to change? I'd like to keep my queries minimal, the empty columns will be used later. Is this bad practice? The fact that changing servers broke this makes me think it's either a difference in mysqli versions, or the configuration of mysqld.

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: You're not executing your query.

Comment: If that is all your code relating to this query @JayBlanchard is correct.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it was just a mistake, forgot to copy the execution. As I said in the OP, code works fine if I switch databases to the old one, so it must be a configuration or version problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This script was running fine

I find that very hard to believe. You have specified that none of the 10 attributes can be null, only 2 have default values (id, access), and your script only sets 6 of the values on INSERT.

If you have specified that a value MUST NOT BE NULL then you must either specify a default or set a value.

If the script works on the old server, it must have a different schema to that above.

Comment: It could be, both databases were created using phpmyadmin. I will set default values and report back

Comment: Query worked fine when the missing columns were set to default to NULL. I guess the old server had a different phpmyadmin setting, maybe modifications to the schema as you said.