# Mysqli not inserting on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am making a system in PHP that handles lists of prices of certain products. But trying to make an insert in the database gives nothing. Where is the error of this code? It simply doesn't insert into the database...

It even prints "ok" but doesn't insert... :(

```
<?php

include_once("../config.inc.php");
include_once("../mysql_connect.inc.php");

$solicitante = null;
$ccusto = null;
$data = null;
$solicitante = null;
$ccusto = null;
$obs = null;
$empresa1 = null;
$empresa2 = null;
$empresa3 = null;
$vendedor1 = null;
$vendedor2 = null;
$vendedor3 = null;
$prazo = null;
$empresa_id = null;
$obs2 = null;
$fechado = null;
$frete1 = null;
$desconto1 = null;
$prazo_pagamento1 = null;

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_pedidos (data, solicitante, ccusto, obs, empresa1, empresa2, empresa3, vendedor1, vendedor2, vendedor3, prazo, empresa_id, obs2, fechado, frete1, desconto1, prazo_pagamento1) ".
"VALUES (NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if ($stmt = $mysql_db->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sissssssssisisss", $solicitante, $ccusto, $obs, $empresa1, $empresa2, $empresa3, $vendedor1, $vendedor2, $vendedor3, $prazo, $empresa_id, $obs2, $fechado, $frete, $desconto, $prazo_pagamento1);
    $stmt->execute();
    $pedido_id = $mysql_db -> insert_id;
    $stmt->close();
    print 'ok';
} else {
    print 'erro';
}

?>
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: near to bind param you have a 16 parameters, buin in your query have 17 parameters

Comment: and you didnt set $table_pedidos

Comment: @manowar_manowar $table_pedidos is set on config.inc.php. And it has 17 parameters on the query but 16 question marks because one of the parameters is passed as NOW()

Comment: @Fred-ii- error_reporting and mysqli->error are giving nothing

Comment: I had a similar experience where a script used to work on one installation but not on another one. Make sure every single column in the database either has a default value set, or is specified in the query, otherwise the INSERT will not work.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysql_db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira You're welcome. Glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: Thank you it gave me an error!

Comment: The problem was the defaults of the columns as @aron9forever suggested. Thank you all.

Comment: Then I feel that @aron9forever should be or have posted an answer for it Filipe, *it's only right* ;-) and to mark the question as solved. Edit: ah he just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the database schema, some values might not have defaults set and so if you try to insert something without specifying all columns even with dummy values, the query will fail.

Either set default values for all columns in the database, or specify all of them in the query.

In replacing:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

with:

```
if(!$stmt->execute()){
   trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysql_db->error, E_USER_WARNING);
   }
```

would have signaled a database error.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Some more information on this in one of my previous questions [Mysqli INSERT not working unless all columns are present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171368/mysqli-insert-not-working-unless-all-columns-are-present)

Comment: @Fred-ii- heh, yead, I noticed the comment right after writing. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you don't mind [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35656475/2) I made.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

```
$mdate =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$insert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name,date) VALUES (?,?)");
$insert->bind_param("ss", $a_name $mdate);
$insert->execute();
```

Comment: Sure, *"that"* worked. However, it doesn't answer the question in regards to a solution as to *"why"* it failed. The actual solution here was my comment to the OP, [being this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655450/mysqli-not-inserting-on-php?noredirect=1#comment58992369_35655450)

Comment: and *"Try this"* are reserved for comments really.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.